# Powershell does not capture stderr to variable in script

Tags: powershell

I would like to call openssl via a Powershell script and in case of an error capture stderr to a variable to log the error. Actually, the openssl error is what I want to see here - this is not the problem. My problem is how to deal with the situation when such a problem with openssl occurs.

It works like a charm when I do this directly in the Powershell itself:

```
PS > $bin = 'C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe'
PS > $parm =  'smime', '-encrypt', '-aes-256-gcm', '-outform', 'PEM', '-out', '<SomePathHere>\testd.xml.pem', '-in', '<SomePathHere>\testd.xml', '<SomePathHere>\Zert\part1.pem'
PS > & $bin $parm
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
Error opening recipient certificate file <SomePathHere>\part1.pem
2032:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:391:fopen('<SomePathHere>\part1.pem','rb')
2032:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:393:
unable to load certificate
unable to write 'random state'

PS > $out = & $bin $parm 2>&1
PS > $out
openssl.exe : Loading 'screen' into random state - done
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:8
+ $out = & $bin $parm 2>&1
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Loading 'screen...om state - done:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Error opening recipient certificate file <SomePathHere>\part1.pem
7228:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:391:fopen('<SomePathHere>\part1.pem','rb')
7228:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:393:
unable to load certificate
unable to write 'random state'
```

When I put the same code into a script and run it as a script, stderr does not make it into the variable. Anybody having an idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the relevant code of the script:

```
        $OpenSSLParam = 'smime', '-encrypt', '-aes-256-gcm', '-outform', 'PEM', '-out', $OpenSSLAusgabeDatei, '-in', $OpenSSLEingabeDatei, $OpenSSLSchluessel
        $Old_ErrorActionPreference = $ErrorActionPreference
        $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
        $outssl = & $OpenSSLBinary $OpenSSLParam 2>&1
        if($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
        {
            $LogMsg = @"
OpenSSL-Fehler!
Exit Code: $LASTEXITCODE
Aufruf: $osslcmd
Error: $outssl
"@
            Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source $EventlogSource -EventId 1002 -EntryType Error -Message $LogMsg
            exit $LASTEXITCODE
        }
```

If I run this through the debugger, I get:

```
PS > <SomePathHere>\encrypt_xml.ps1
Treffer Zeilenhaltepunkt bei "<SomePathHere>\encrypt_xml.ps1:71"
[DBG]: PS >> $LASTEXITCODE
2

[DBG]: PS >> $outssl

[DBG]: PS >>
```

I'd love to understand why Powershell does not populate the `$outssl` Variable. Any help is very much appreciated. As a goodie, I'd love to know if there might be a way to only capture the `openssl` stderr without the stderr of Powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I have found the problem. Powershell behaves as told!

If I replace

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
```

with

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
```

I get the desired result!